# Error when using OpenCV with DarkNet - for generating anchors for own dataset

Tags: homebrew, darknet

[image]

After compiling darknet with Opencv=1, and then calculating anchors for my dataset :

./darknet detector calc_anchors JIO/obj.data -num_of_clusters 9 -width 416 -heigh 416

ERROR :   k-means++ can't be used without OpenCV, because there is used cvKMeans2 implementation

But, in the screenshot, on seeing pkg-config flags for opencv, it prints the paths for opencv.pc

PYTHON :2.7.15

OPENCV :2.4

Opencv installed using Homebrew on mac

Comment: I am having the exact problem, May I know if you got the solution?

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: No i havent @dnez